# Массив значения типа double

Tags: c

Здравствуйте, мне нужно создать 2 восьми элементных массива значения типа `double`, в 1 массив я ввожу 8 значений, программа должна накапливать в элементах второго массива суммы первого с нарастающим итогом.
Например,

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8   (в первый массив ввожу восемь значении)
1  3  6  10  15  21 28 36 (второй массив суммирует значения первого массива)
```

Программа работает с типом `int`, но не с `double`, c типом `double` программа выдает ошибку "Прекращена работа программы".

Вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define eight 8
int main ()
{
    setlocale(0,"");

    int  one,two,sum;
    int  array_one[eight],array_two[eight];

    printf ("Массивы:\n");
    for (one = 0; one < eight; one++)
        scanf("%d", &array_one[one]);
    printf ("\n");

    printf ("*****************\n");

    for (one = 0; one < eight; one++)
        printf("%d ", array_one[one]);
    printf ("\n");
    for (one = 0,sum = 0,two = 0; one < eight; one++)
    {
        sum +=array_one[one];
        array_two[two] = two + sum;
        printf ("%d ",array_two[two]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вот код с типом `double`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define eight 8
int main ()
{
    setlocale(0,"");

    double  one,two,sum;
    double  array_one[eight],array_two[eight];

    printf ("Массивы:\n");
    for (one = 0; one < eight; one++)
        scanf("%lf", &array_one[one]);
    printf ("\n");

    printf ("*****************\n");

    for (one = 0; one < eight; one++)
        printf("%f ", array_one[one]);
    printf ("\n");
    for (one = 0,sum = 0,two = 0; one < eight; one++)
    {
        sum +=array_one[one];
        array_two[two] = two + sum;
        printf ("%f ",array_two[two]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а компилятор у вас разве не выдает ошибку при испльзовании double в качестве индекса массива?

Comment: @DreamChild, надо же, оказывается gcc 4.8.2 так не нравятся double индексы, что он вообще не компилирует (я предполагал warning).

Comment: @avp я не знаю подробностей стандарта этого языка (может такое и возможно), но у меня VC++ и gcc (на ideone) отказались это дело компилировать

Comment: `#define eight 8` make me unsee it

Comment: @VladD тут скорее всего угадывается рука наших отечественных горе-преподавателей, которые продолжают вколачивать в головы студентов практики стогодовалой давности

Comment: @DreamChild: Возможно, это сработало правило против «магических констант». Но не `eight` же, а `DATA_SIZE`. А то cargo cult какой-то получается.

Comment: @VladD ну кстати да, практика вдвойне бессмысленная - хранить в этой переменной что-то кроме 8 было бы странно, при этом я подразумевал, что использование  #define для "эмуляции" констант при живом const - это похоже на пережиток древности

Comment: Тогда может есть смысл создать вопрос аля "самые популярные и устарелые техники, которыми всё ещё учат"?

Comment: @m0nhawk боюсь для этой темы не то что вопроса, кандидатской диссертации маловато будет

Comment: @DreamChild: Ну, под чистым C возможно это всё ещё идиоматичная конструкция, я не в тренде. В C++ макросы уже, как я понимаю, давно стараются избегать по возможности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не буду останавливаться на самом коде, отвечу сразу на вопрос. Эта строчка неправильная:

```
double one, two, sum;
```

Тут смешано несколько разных переменных. `one` и `two` - переменные которые используются для доступа (индексации) к массиву, потому лучше использовать:

```
int one, two;
```

Но лучше так:

```
size_t one, two;
```

А вот `double sum` оставить, необходимо именно сумма для чисел с двойной точностью (double).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а если нужно ввести в первый массив вещественные числа ? то тогда с типом int не получиться

Comment: >а если нужно ввести в первый массив вещественные числа ? то тогда с типом int не получиться


разве тип элементов массива кк-то зависит от типа его индекса? Разумеется, нет.

Небольшой оффтоп: может, кто-то знает, как в теперь вставлять цитаты в комментарии? На Хэшкоде это можно было сделать, добавив перед цитируемым текстом символ >

Comment: @Dick не совсем понял вопрос, я говорю про индексацию элементов - то-есть их положение в массиве, а оно уж никак не может быть не целым.

Comment: понял), получается тип элемента может быть double, а индекс int ? (прощу прошения за глупые вопросы только осваиваю Массивы)

Comment: @Dick да, именно. Тип может быть совершенно любой, главное чтобы память была выделена, а вот индекс лучше вообще `size_t` (он же `unsigned int` - без знаковое целое); потому-что конструкции с отрицательными индексами: `array[-1]`, - практически не используются.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ (как заметил в комментарии @IvanZakirov) неправильный. Почему-то мне показалось, что в программе что-то вроде `array_two[two] = two += sum;`

На самом деле пока не знаю, в чем ошибка. Скорее всего в вопросе автор привел не тот код.

В обеих случаях ошибка вот здесь:

```
sum +=array_one[one];
array_two[two] = two + sum;  // здесь индекс two зависит от ранее введенных данных
```

Понятия не имею, в чем смысл Ваших вычислений, но перед использованием вычисляемого индекса стоит проверить, что он адресует элемент *внутри* массива.

В первой программе та же ошибка, видимо она не проявляется из-за разницы в размере int (4 байта) и double (8 байт), т.е. во второй запись мимо массива трет какие-то важные для работы программы данные (скорее всего адрес возврата).

И, естественно, во второй программе все-таки сделайте индексы (`one`, `two` ...) int, вместо double (очень уж глаз режет).

По поводу выбора имен, думаю, сейчас Вам еще выскажут по полной...

Comment: не пойму, как у него увеличивается индекс второго массива ?

Comment: @IvanZakirov, спасибо, это моя ошибка. Ответ неправильный. Вы правы индекс `two` никогда не меняется (остается 0). Тогда не знаю почему программа падает.

Comment: Мне кажется программа падает потому что тип индекса массива double - допустим С++ пропускает этот факт т.к. он не задан  и не меняется, он допустим у него всегда = 0 или чему там по умолчанию в С++.. НО - его счетчик тоже double и насколько итерация его увеличивает ? на целое число или допустим на 0.1... если на дробное, то пока оно дойдет до условия заканчивающее цикл явно выйдет за пределы индекса. Ну мне так кажется.. я в С++ не программирую, может и не прав.